# How to not symlink the priv directory for Rebar3 eunit tests?

Tags: erlang, eunit, rebar3

When using:

```
$ rebar3 as test eunit
```

it compiles the code into ebin, but the other directories are symlinked in the `_build/test/lib` folder. I've tried using profile `test` by modifying:

```
{relx, [{dev_mode, false}]}
```

This works only for `_build/test/rel` directory but not the lib directory. So during tests they are referencing the lib symlink directories. Is there a way to have these directories not symlinked to the original, but actual copies provided like the release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick look at the `rebar3` code there doesn't seem to be a way to force copying of these directories. It looks like the `priv` directory is always symlinked [here](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/blob/fb363cd8de68e9113e407ac0be049cacdd9ddd07/src/rebar_prv_compile.erl#L204). Even though the function used is called `symlink_or_copy`, it only ends up copying when [there is an error while creating the symlink](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/blob/ac8ee44f18a7b94ac86b27e33b3573ef389707a7/src/rebar_file_utils.erl#L96).

[`dev_mode` is a `relx` option](https://github.com/erlware/relx/blob/d3d9bc73afaf4b145d7e6d484096534b297faf7f/src/rlx_config.erl#L182), that's why it doesn't affect `rebar3` features.

If you want this feature added you can create a feature request explaining your use case, why you think it would be useful and it might get implemented.